# Html Form - run Javascript when input is equal to "Nearby"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, geolocation

I have some javascript that is getting the users latitude and longitude from their device to be used for a local search.

Everything is functioning correctly, but because the geolocation function creates a pop up warning to the user to "Allow" or "Don't Allow" their location to be used, I'd like to not run the script unless the user has specifically selected "nearby" as the location.

Here's my java that does the geolocation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

x = navigator.geolocation;
x.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);

function success(position){
    document.getElementById('lat1').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('long1').value = position.coords.longitude;
}
function failure()
{
// do nothing
}
```

Here's my form.  The input `id="search-box-2"` is the input element I want to use to change the behavior of the script.  If `input id="search-box-2"` has `value="Nearby"`, then I'd like for the javascript function to execute.  Otherwise, ideally it would do nothing.

```
   <form id="search-form" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8, utf-8" action="page.php">

   <fieldset>
       <input id="search-box-1" name="search" type="text" placeholder="" />
       <input name="lat" type="text" id="lat1" value="" />
       <input name="long" type="text" id="long1" value="" />
       <input id="search-box-2" name="where" type="text" placeholder="City or State" value=""/>   
    <div class="button-holder">
       <button class="button-homepage" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So, in summary, I'd like the script to run only if the search-box-2 field value equals 'nearby'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

Trigger this function on submit

```
function notNearby() {
  if($('#search-box-2').val() != 'nearby') {  
    x = navigator.geolocation;
    x.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);

    function success(position){
        document.getElementById('lat1').value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('long1').value = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    function failure()
    {
    // do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <button class="button-homepage" onclick='notNearby();' type="submit">Search</button>
```

Either that or I did not understand your question